# How can you share session information between PHP and Perl CGI?

Tags: php, session, cgi

I have a thirdparty script that I don't want to rewrite in CGI/Perl, so I was thinking, if I set some session information via PHP, there must be a way to retrieve that same data with CGI. I'm not big on Perl, can you guys point me in the right direction?

```
//php
session_start();
$_SESSION['myvar']=1234;
```

So how do I access this with Perl/CGI?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP's default file-based session handler basically just writes out a `serialize()` copy of the $_SESSION array. The file is usually named "sess_XXX" where XXX is the session ID. There's Perl libraries that let it read PHP's serialize format (http://hurring.com/scott/code/perl/serialize/ for one, from a quick googling).

If you get the session ID and session save path from PHP into Perl, it'll be trivial to read the session data in Perl.